# Is there a way to add new tab in WordPress Gutenberg editor

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, create-guten-block

I am completely new to Gutenberg and I need to add a new tab in the setting section Please check this screenshot

[image]

I Have created some blocks for Gutenberg but no experience in this. I tried this code

```
import { TabPanel } from '@wordpress/components';

    const onSelect = ( tabName ) => {
        console.log( 'Selecting tab', tabName );
    };

    const MyTabPanel = () => (
        <TabPanel className="my-tab-panel"
            activeClass="active-tab"
            onSelect={ onSelect }
            tabs={ [
                {
                    name: 'tab1',
                    title: 'Tab 1',
                    className: 'tab-one',
                },
                {
                    name: 'tab2',
                    title: 'Tab 2',
                    className: 'tab-two',
                },
            ] }>
            {
                ( tab ) => <p>{ tab.title }</p>
            }
        </TabPanel>
    );
```

But didn't help me. Anyone here please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In the screenshot you provided, the location you are attempting to add a tab to is the Settings Header
([gutenberg/packages/edit-post/src/components/sidebar/settings-header](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/e703aee273ab34477d40044f5f3160d7009e0e39/packages/edit-post/src/components/sidebar/settings-header/index.js)) for which there is not currently a slot in the Gutenberg API to extend from (*although this could potentially be done, it's best to not interfere with core UI*).

The prefered method to add to the Admin UI is to use an provided [SlotFill](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/slotfills/) for custom content, currently there are:

- PluginBlockSettingsMenuItem
- PluginDocumentSettingPanel
- PluginMoreMenuItem
- PluginPostPublishPanel
- PluginPostStatusInfo
- PluginPrePublishPanel
- PluginSidebar
- PluginSidebarMoreMenuItem

The [PluginSidebar slot](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/slotfills/plugin-sidebar/) is useful for adding custom content that is specific for your plugins/blocks purpose. The main point to consider is whether the content you wish to add applies just to your block, the post/page as a whole or is some other 'global' setting to do with a plugin.

If your content applies to the whole post/page, the [PluginPostStatusInfo slot](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/slotfills/plugin-post-status-info/) may be a good location to add to. You could also add your own [Panel](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/panel/) that appears underneath the "Document" tab.

If the content is block-specific, then you can use the  to add custom controls underneath "Block" tab that contextually show when your block is selected. This would also be a good place for meta field values that are specific to the block or custom controls for colors/display options related to your block.

The official WordPress Gutenberg documentation also has a tutorial on [Block Controls: Block Toolbar and Settings Sidebar](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/block-controls-toolbar-and-sidebar/) which walks through some common scenarios for adding your own settings in Blocks.